# How to implement android background services

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk, sfdcmobilesdk-android

we are currently implementing Beacons and Beacon zones into mobile studio. The services for IOs are running smoothly but Android keeps giving us a hard time. After a while, the devices do not receive any notification anymore, it seems like to be limited for some reason. Is there anyone who has experience in implementing background services for Android?

We are using salesforce SDK for Android (http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/location/add-beacons.html). Apparently some permissions that are responsible for Access to GPS and Background Services have to be adjusted.

Permission for GPS:

`uses-permissionandroid:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/`

Permissions for Background Services:

```
uses-permissionandroid:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/
```

The background services are only listed for Android 10, how can we activate those for former versions?

Comment: I can see that Salesforce is involved here, but I think the heart of this question is about Android. You might consider posing this question over on Stackoverflow or Software Engineering Stack Exchange (if you do, try to keep the focus off of Salesforce so they don't just try to toss you back over here).

Comment: Hi Derek, thanks for your reply. I will do as you said and hopefully get information over there.